# When was Samsung rv420 laptop released?

Tags: laptop

I'm triying to figure out how "old" is the Samsung rv420 computer model. I bought it around 3 years ago, in fact around april 2012 (maybe a month later or sooner), in fact windows installation is around that date. The windows 7 was pre-installed when i bought it.
I want to know when was this particular model of laptop, at least in US or even better in my country (Argentine), released and started to sell.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know when was this particular model of laptop, at least in
>   US or even better in my country (Argentine), released and started to
>   sell.

It is unlikely this model was even sold outside of Argentine.  I see no evidence of it every existing on any North American online retailer.  There is no North American product website for the laptop, it only exists on the Samsung Hong Kong website, which indicates this is model for a specific region.

It was released after `June 15, 2010` based on the fact it comes with Office 2010 installed.  The CPU itself was release within Q1'2011 specifically in `February 2011`.  Based on that fact I would estimate this was Q2'2011 product.

Based on the fact the review I found happened on 06/24/2011 given all the information my estimate is likely correct.

Comment: Thank you!! I never heard of Q1, Q2, that refers to quarters of year right?

Comment: My BIOS was Phoenix Technologies LTD 01PQ 31/03/2011.

Comment: That just indicates the BIOS was released in March 2011 not that the laptop was released in 2011.  Its very unlikely Samsung was able to roll out a product release in less then 60 days.  If I were to provide a more specific estimate I would guess a late May 2011 or early June 2011 release.

Comment: Hi, My computer was actually *made* in Argentina. The components itself were made in other countries, but here they designed and assembled it, it has a label in the case. I thought that label meant it was sold here, but no it means actually made (only assembling of actually finished components, but still we do at least some of the work). That explains why it's not on other countries.